What will be the recurrence relation of method which finds the sum of array elements?
public static int sumRecursive(int[] arr, int i) {
    if (i == arr.length) {
        return 0;
    }
    return arr[i] + sumRecursive(arr, ++i);
}

F(i) = arr\[i\] + F(i + 1)
or
F(arr, i) = arr\[i\] + F(arr, i + 1)
F(n) = 0, when i becomes equal to the length of the array(n), then we return 0.
which one is correct from them or there's better way to write this?

Both F(i) = arr[i] + F(i + 1) or F(arr, i) = arr[i] + F(arr, i + 1) are correct since arr[] is never altered it can be treated as constant and does not need to be passed as parameter of F.

What is the purpose of the recurrence relation? If it is to determine the time complexity, then you wouldn't have arr[i] in there. If it is to write it as pseudo code, then both are OK.

A better way to write the recursion (in pseudocode) would be fn sum(arr, i, j) {return arr[i] if i == j; midrange = i + floor((j - i)/2); return sum(arr, i, i+midrange) + sum(arr, midrange+1, j);}.  This has a recursion depth of log(size(arr)) vs size(arr) for yours, so it can handle much larger arrays.
